# How does Vue router help to load page faster?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuex, lazy-loading, vue-router

So I just got into the topic of Vue router today. I know that it helps contents to load faster by preventing the whole page to refresh everytime but to only bring necessary components.

But didn't it just load the whole bundle.js file (by Webpack) upon visiting the home page already? So since we already loaded the whole JS file upon first visit, wouldn't it be unnecessary to call separate JS files when visiting different pages?

[This](https://vueschool.io/lessons/how-to-lazy-load-routes-with-vue-router?friend=vuejs) is the lesson I was watching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main benefit you're talking about is navigating from one URL to another.

Normally, this would require a full page load, eg

```
Page1.html   click link   Page2.html
 - JS                           - JS
 - CSS                          - CSS
 - Images                       - Images
```

but by using a component router, you only need to swap out the parts of the page that have changed without reloading all your layout.

This is really at the core of what is known as a [Single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) where your app is quite literally one HTML page with parts within it that respond to URL changes.

The URL is able to be changed without requiring a full page load by either manipulating the [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) (aka *hash*) or by using the browser's [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History).

In Vue Router, this choice is controlled by the [`mode` configuration](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html).

---

> *"But didn't it just load the whole bundle.js file"*

Not necessarily. See [Lazy Loading Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer. So to clarify, even if I see app.js (webpack bundle js file) under Network tab in web dev tool, it doesn't include ALL files?

Lazy loading will automatically EXCLUDE unneccsary .js files for that specific page, is that right?

Comment: Correct, but it's not only JS files (images, fonts and CSS too). Lazy loading routes creates [chunks](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) that are only loaded (via an asynchronous request) when those specific routes are requested.